# Metaphor for the action "Import New and Select Only Some"

Tags: meaning, expressions

This is for a program that im doing, i need to recieve/load a good number of pictures and then select some, in order to move them to a new treatment fase called "Worshop".

However i need to name this process whit a sybolic name, because allows comprehension. However I'm out of ideas... I thought a few names like "Import", "Select" but i was looking for names like "Worshop" but for this task. If u have any sujestion, it would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean _workshop_?

Comment: No workshop its where i treat/improve objects. The process i want to give a name is more like saying i want this wood chair to be improved! and this door too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Enhancement studio'.

How about 'picture book' like an old scrap book? Picture wall? Picture box? Image farm? Art store? Picture house. Art forest. Art factory. Hopefully this will spark something in you!  Selection box. Art palette. Image stash. Picture factory.

Comment: Great! I'm glad it helped! I enjoy coming up with those sorts of things. Bit like doing puzzles! 